# Sentence-transformers installlation in offline Kaggle competition

Tags: python, installation, package, kaggle, sentence-transformers

In a Kaggle competition, submissions must be offline. Therfore, I need to download some packages, like sentence-transformers.

I have downloaded the source code from github and uploaded it, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/code/narnaoot/installing-packages-without-internet-for-kaggle)

But I receive this error (knowing that all dependencies are already satisfied)

```
Building wheels for collected packages: sentence-transformers
  Building wheel for sentence-transformers (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:745: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.
      
              By 2023-Sep-26, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.
      
              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
      error: could not create 'build': Read-only file system
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sentence-transformers
  Running setup.py clean for sentence-transformers
Failed to build sentence-transformers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for sentence-transformers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Did anyone got the same erroe.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can put sentence-transformers (or any other lib) into a dataset, link it to your notebook, then copy to working, which is writable, and then build, like

```
!cp -r /kaggle/input/dataset-with-all-stuff/sentence_transformers ./
!pip install ./sentence_transformers/sentence-transformers-2.2.2/sentence-transformers-2.2.2 --no-index -find-links=file:///kaggle/working/sentence_transformers/
```